# Where is the Ubuntu file system root directory in Windows Subsystem for Linux and vice versa?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu subsystem on Windows 10 (after enabling feature in settings), but where is the Ubuntu file system root directory located in the drive?

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE**

We (the WSL team) [STRONGLY recommend you do NOT spelunk into the Linux distro data folders](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)
). If you do, data loss and/or corruption is VERY likely

We are working to improve this interop scenario and will announce any progress on our blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/

Comment: @RichTurner I've found there's a very specific (and annoying) reason - corporate policies marking the .ssh folder with the wrong permissions repeatedly means needing to mark the structure as "off limits" to the corporate scripts. But generally - I'd agree with you.

Comment: Although it looks like on boxes with more recent updates - this no longer happens.

Comment: @DannyStaple If you need to change the permissions on files/folders in your Linux distro from Windows, use `wsl.exe`, e.g. `wsl chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id*` - do *not* copy files into these folders via the Windows filesystem.

Comment: @RichTurner: Why don't you guys tunnel Linux metadata like how you already tunnel NTFS metadata?

Comment: @mehrdad We do in 1903 and later via the new P9 server.

Comment: @RichTurner: Thanks for the reply! I'm confused though... 1903 requires accessing it as a network resource though, doesn't it? If you tunneled the attributes the same way you tunneled NTFS metadata then it'd be possible to just edit the files locally. That suggests to me that's not exactly what you're doing?

Comment: @mehrdad WSL implements a P9 fileserver, exposing/marshalling files from/to the distro's filesystem as any P9 fileserver would. This way there is no NTFS metadata to marshal. Please watch Craig Loewen & Ben Hillis' session at Build 2919 for more info

Comment: @RichTurner: *"This way there is no NTFS metadata to marshal."* Yes... so NTFS tunneling is *not* what you're doing, in contradiction with what you said earlier. So we go back to my first question: didn't you guys tunnel the WSL metadata *instead* of using a fileserver, just like NTFS already does with other metadata?

Comment: @mehrdad Where did I say we were marshalling NTFS metadata? P9 marshals file metadata (i.e. timestamps, permissions, filename, etc.), not NTFS data.

Comment: @RichTurner: Well it was where I asked *"Why don't you guys tunnel Linux metadata like how you already tunnel NTFS metadata?"* and you said *"We do in 1903 and later"*. I was specifically asking, why don't you just have the NTFS file system driver tunnel the Linux metadata (e.g. LXATTRB... or maybe all EAs) along with all the other metadata it already tunnels. It's basically exactly the same problem in the same situation where programs using file replacements instead of truncation, so I'm confused why you don't try the same solution you already had for this problem for the past decade or two.

Comment: @mehrdad: I think you're misunderstanding how filesystem integration works in WSL. To summarize: In WSL, we add Linux metadata to each file & folder under the distro FS's root folder. The Linux syscalls use the Linux and Windows FS metadata to calculate effective metdata (inc. permissions, etc.). WSL also synthesizes Linux permissions from Windows files/folders when accessing /mnt/c/ etc. In WSL >= 1903, we've integrated a P9 fileserver through which Windows can access Linux files. The P9 fileserver marshals data and metadata as one would expect

Comment: @mehrdad: If you have further questions, please post your questions in an issue on the GitHub repo (https://github.com/microsoft/wsl) where we have more room to explain more thoroughly.

Answer (score 650, accepted):

For Ubuntu installed from the Windows store:

> Each distribution you install through the store is installed to that
>   application's appdata directory. For example:
>   `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState` [- benhillis](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/402#issuecomment-321853125)

For WSL2 you can access to home directory from windows (Windows 10 build 18342) like this :

```
\\wsl$
```

In earlier iterations of Windows Subsystem for Linux, the Ubuntu file system was at `%localappdata%\Lxss` (e.g., `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Lxss` - replace the **Username** with your Username on Windows). See [the WSL blog post on File System Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/):

> The primary file system used by WSL is VolFs. It is used to store the
>   Linux system files, as well as the content of your Linux home
>   directory. As such, VolFs supports most features the Linux VFS
>   provides, including Linux permissions, symbolic links, FIFOs, sockets,
>   and device files.
>
> VolFs is used to mount the VFS root directory, using
>   `%LocalAppData%\lxss\rootfs` as the backing storage. In addition, a
>   few additional VolFs mount points exist, most notably `/root` and
>   `/home` which are mounted using `%LocalAppData%\lxss\root` and
>   `%LocalAppData%\lxss\home` respectively. The reason for these separate
>   mounts is that when you uninstall WSL, the home directories are not
>   removed by default, so any personal files stored there will be
>   preserved.

### CAUTION

Creating/modifying any files within the Linux subsystem using Windows apps & tools can cause Data corruption and data loss in Ubuntu subsystem! (Thanks to [Rich Turner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-nt-subsystem-and-vice/759885#comment1299704_759885) for suggesting these words of caution!) **This is absolutely *not* supported.** From the same blog post:

> #### Interoperability with Windows
>
> While VolFs files are stored in regular files on Windows in the
>   directories mentioned above, interoperability with Windows is not
>   supported. If a new file is added to one of these directories from
>   Windows, it lacks the EAs needed by VolFs, so VolFs doesn’t know what
>   to do with the file and simply ignores it. Many editors will also
>   strip the EAs when saving an existing file, again making the file
>   unusable in WSL.

---

Your Windows file system is located at `/mnt/c` in the Bash shell environment.

[image]

Source: [Dustin Kirkland's blog](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/03/ubuntu-on-windows.html), [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Thanks very much, another question, I install git using `apt-get install git`, so where does the git executable file located? Newbie to Ubuntu.

Comment: try `type git` to see the git executable location.

Comment: @July: Please [open a new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new, unrelated question or, better yet, search for an existing question that fits the bill. Comments are not generally meant for follow-up questions. :-)

Comment: Lxss was hidden on my file system... caused a bit of head scratching for an infuriating minute or two. Now I've created a shortcut, but I still can't seem to unhide it.

Comment: @Ogaday you can't unhide it using the properties window because it's marked as a system directory. You can unhide it using `attrib -s -h lxss` which will unmark it as a system directory also.

Comment: How come I can't see anything in the home dir? I can see files in there from bash.

Comment: @mpen I would suggest you to ask a new question.

Comment: It looks like the location has either changed or different between systems as mine is in a different location. I've posted below with my location.

Comment: Is it possible to access the rest of the file system before its root? I have websites installed in my C:\Documents folder. Is it possible to access those from Windows Bash?

Comment: @Trip yes. your whole `C:` drive can be accessed at`/mnt/c`.

Comment: @souravc Could you please add an important note to the top of your answer, STRONGLY recommending against creating/modifying any files within LXSS using Windows apps & tools: Data corruption and loss is very likely if you do!

Comment: I don't understand. If I can't safely modify the files in Windows tools what is the point of running it in Windows? cygwin still seems superior to that...

Comment: On a windows box you must go to view->options->Change folder and search options and uncheck "Hide protected operating system files" to be able to see the lxss folder in Windows Explorer. Confused me for a while.

Comment: @RichTurner Does this work in both directions? In oher words, is data corrupion also likely if you are working with files that were created in Windows, from within a Ubuntu instance?

Comment: Please read the post mentioned above: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/. It's safe to access the Windows filesystem from WSL which is why we mount your drives under `/mnt/<drive>/`, but is NOT safe (yet) to access Linux filesystem from Windows which is why we don't provide easy access to the distro filesystems.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 If you want to access files in both Windows and Linux, store them on your Windows Filesystem, and access them as usual in Windows, or via `/mnt/<drive>/<path>` in Linux.

Comment: @RichTurner yeah I ended up doing that plus creating a symlink for even more convenient Linux access

Comment: Good idea. I've created a symlinks in my home folder from `dev` to `/mnt/c/dev` for easy access to my dev projects.

Comment: this answered so many questions.  thank you for the help!!!!

Comment: Should probably change it from e.g. to i.e.

Comment: is this still true several years later?

Comment: I also just ran into this issue, using an Apache on Windows on a web document root located in the WSL/Ubuntu 18 directory. The web application (read: apache) creates various cache files, which later cannot be written to by a utility within the Linux machine. As an idea, I would suggesst that the filesystem by default adds read and write permissions to files created from outside.

Comment: thanks, a sidenote: also using  Arch and it is under %localappdata%\Local\Packages\52569scottxu.ArchLinux_xhwh673y3hxf8\

Answer (score 54):

This seems to have changed since Bash was originally introduced, and does not apply to distributions from the Windows Store, or maybe it is not consistent for all systems as my home directory is located in another location:

```
%localappdata%\lxss\home\{username}
```

or:

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\lxss\{username}
```

Where `{user}` is your Windows Username and `{username}` is your UNIX Username set during install.

So the root directory would be:

```
%localappdata%\lxss
```

Note that the root directory may not be visible in Windows Explorer from the `%localappdata%` directory. You should be able to access it anyways by typing it in the 'address bar' of Explorer.

Comment: My machine can't find: "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Lxss\{username}" or "%localappdata%\Lxss\home\{username}" but "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\lxss\{username}" works. I.E. use "lxss" NOT "Lxss"

Comment: My system has the rootfs subdirectory, but rootfs/home is empty while ./home has my user account and files. It seems safest to just go to %localappdata%\lxss and then explore around from there to see which layout you have, plus directly browsing to that address avoids issues with the lxss directory being hidden.

Comment: @JoeCodeswelluser601770 That's odd. Windows filesystems are normally case insensitive. I can enter %localappdata%\Lxss or %localappdata%\lxss and both go to %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\lxss

Comment: Note that this folder (lxss) did not appear in my windows explorer listing of folders in AppData\Local, even with hidden folders view enabled. I had to manually paste add the folder lxss to the explorer bar to get to the files here e.g. edit the folder "url" to there

Comment: Alternatively, you can go to the Desktop, right-click "New->Shortcut" and paste a path like C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\lxss\home\yourname

Comment: I'm having a similar issues: 1. No lxss in Local folder (even when hidden shown. 2. Full C:\ path does not work after trying second time even after spell check and proper windows and bash username. 3. %localappdata%\lxss\home\{username} works like a charm everytime, thank you NicholasJohn16 and Colin D

Comment: Just to add to the many different examples already mentioned, all of the files on my computer are directly under `%localappdata%\lxss`. There's no sub-directory with my 'UNIX' username; *home* is a sub-directory tho and under *home* is a sub-directory for my UNIX username.

Answer (score 17):

If you install Linux from MS Market:

- [Free Ubuntu in Windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6)
- [Free Open Suse in Windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/opensuse-leap-42/9njvjts82tjx)

they placed distros under:

```
$ cat /proc/registry/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Lxss/\{861c29b4-ebe2-49a5-8a22-7e53a27934a0\}/BasePath
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState
```

Default distro defined by:

```
bash# cat /proc/registry/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Lxss/DefaultDistribution
{861c29b4-ebe2-49a5-8a22-7e53a27934a0}
```

Linux root is deeper:

```
c:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Packages/46932SUSE.openSUSELeap42.2_022rs5jcyhyac/LocalState/rootfs
```

PS. I used Cygwin to explore registry keys.

If using PowerShell for the same goal, the commands would be:

```
# obtain the value of the ID of the default Linux distribution (and store it in a variable to avoid escaping characters issues):
$DEFAULT_LXSS_ID = (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\ -name DefaultDistribution)

# which will have a value like:
echo  $DEFAULT_LXSS_ID
{bde539d6-0c87-4e12-9599-1dcd623fbf07}

# display the directory containing the rootfs Windows directory (mapped to the / Linux directory)
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\$DEFAULT_LXSS_ID -name BasePath | Format-List -property "BasePath"
%LocalAppData%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState
```

PPS. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

Comment: It's really good that you made this more-useable (for a bigger variety of different situations) by noting that "**[you] used Cygwin to explore registry keys.**"

Comment: This is the answer that helped me the most. Somehow I had set a custom location for the Basepath during inital setup. I was able to read that location by manually looking it up in the windows registry editor.

Comment: `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\{GUID}/BasePath`.
Very nice. That registry value helped me find the location of my distro. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can quickly open Bash from a File Explorer window of the opened folder by typing `bash` in the location bar.

It's enough.

Also you can add a context menu item. I personally don`t recommend it if not needed, because adding shortcuts to the context menu uses more RAM.

https://www.howtogeek.com/270810/how-to-quickly-launch-a-bash-shell-from-windows-10s-file-explorer/

Comment: Does not work for me. It opens command prompt and launches bash.

Comment: @blablatros yes but in folder in bash in witch you had explorer open when writing in explorer bar bash and pressing enter. Try in My Documents folder opened Windows Explorer folder and in location bar write bash and it will open ubuntu bash in that folder already :)

Comment: @Kangarooo: I want to access the files through the windows 10 gui as well as vice versa. In my answer above, i found out how to locate the bash directory through the Windows 10 files explorer, and so I proceeded to copy some files from my external hard drive into that directory. However, when I opened the bash terminal and pressed `ls -a`, it didn't show the files I added. Bash was not recognizing the files I dropped in through windows file explorer, which for me has completely defeated the purpose of installing bash on windows.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that worked for me was `%localappdata%\lxss\home\{username}`, where the `{username}` is your BASH username you gave it during the installation. For some reason, after showing hidden folder's lxss refuses to appear in `C:\Users\WINDOWS-USER\AppData\Local\`, and also giving the full `C:\` path with windows and BASH username does not work either.

And please create a desktop shortcut for what works.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for the image location:

```
C:\Users\\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
```