# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 translate working directory

Tags: directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do I translate a directory in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 so that I can invoke a Windows application via Bash and call that working directory as an option?

For Example:

From Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10, I can get the path to my Windows`C:\` drive through `/mnt/c/`, which is useful for opening Windows-based GUI applications from the Bash command line; for instance, I can open Sublime Text with:

```
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe
```

but I'm not sure how to use a command line option that will instruct the Windows application to use something in my current working directory. like:

```
pwd
/home/mark/example
ls
test.txt
mwalle@DESKTOP-LO101K6:~/lyn_solns$ /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe test.txt
Unable to translate current working directory. Using C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

and Sublime Text opens up displaying a new blank file named `test.txt` in the `C:\WINDOWS\system32` folder. I expected it to open the existing `test.txt` in `~\example`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found an answer here:
[Where is the Ubuntu file system root directory in Windows NT subsystem and vice versa?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-nt-subsystem-and-vice). The command to access my Ubuntu user's `test.txt` inside the windows application sublime from the Ubuntu subsystem Bash:

```
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe C:\\Users\\Mark\\Ap
pData\\Local\\lxss\\home\\mwalle\\test.txt
```

Comment: Did you ever find a better workaround? Seems annoying to have to specify the full path to the file, test.txt everytime?

Comment: To elaborate on Mark's solution,
I just set an env variable in my .bashrc to make it less annoying: HOME_WIN='C:\\\Users\\\\{windows user}\\\AppData\\\Local\\\lxss\\\home\\\\{unix username}'

Comment: The Linux home directory is located at the Linux side  of WSL filesystem. Accessing files at the Linux side by Windows applications is NOT recommended, at least in present state of WSL. Please see the WSL blog for details. So, what the OP wants is better not to do at all. The  WSL filesystem location is hidden for a reason.