# Where is /home directory on windows?

Tags: home-directory

How do you find ubuntu's home directory on windows? I've tried searching through windows file explorer by typing `ubuntu/home` nothing shows up. Does anybody have any suggestions? Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to Ubuntu App on Windows a.k.a. WSL? If yes, then this might help [Where is the   Ubuntu file system root directory in Windows Subsystem for Linux and vice versa?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-an) `/home` is inside `/` or `root` which in turn is in LocalAppData

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of Ubuntu's `~/` (a.k.a. `/home/yourusername/`) in Windows 10 is `C:\Users\yourusername\`.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent is C:\Users\

So for you, your home directory would be here:

C:\Users\shushimo

Answer (score 1):

Windows can’t read Linux partitions. That is why you couldn't find the home directory of Ubuntu.

Instead, you could install third-party softwares to do that, like **Ext2Fsd**, **DiskInternals Linux Reader** and so on.

> Reference:
>   https://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/

Comment: CAUTION: Ext2Fsd is known to cause data corruption on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can safely assume that there is no /home directory on Windows. It probably depends on which Windows OS you are talking about. I think Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7 has a /home directory, however. In case I am wrong (I probably am) I suggest waiting for another answer.