# I have a Windows 11 PC. I also installed Ubuntu for Windows 11 with WSL on my PC. How do I find my /home/username directory in Windows explorer?

Tags: windows, home-directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Windows 11 PC.  I also installed Ubuntu for Windows 11 with WSL on my PC.  How do I find
my /home/username directory in Windows explorer?  I looked in c:\users\user_id\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc, but I cannot find anything there.
And I did look in all the directories.

FYI, user_id is my user name on my PC. I also have set things up so I can view hidden files in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is WSL located on my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380253/where-is-wsl-located-on-my-computer).  Look for the section in my answer titled, *"How do I access files in WSL2 from Windows?"*