# How to access Windows files from Linux in WSL?

Tags: command-line, directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm starting to learn how to use the terminal with Ubuntu on WSL (Windows).

Just from the very beginning of the course it says that if you use the `ls` command it should show you your "home" directories, but mine is something like this:

```
(base) paloma@DESKTOP-ISCC0ON:~$ ls
Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-x86_64.sh  anaconda3

(base) paloma@DESKTOP-ISCC0ON:~$
```

And if I try to change directory something like this happens:

```
(base) paloma@DESKTOP-ISCC0ON:~$ ls
Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-x86_64.sh  anaconda3

(base) paloma@DESKTOP-ISCC0ON:~$ cd Documents
-bash: cd: Documents: No such file or directory

(base) paloma@DESKTOP-ISCC0ON:~$
```

Can somebody tell me why is this happening and what can I do, please? I'm a complete newbie.

Answer (score 8):

Everything in [@Tooster's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1442132/1165986) is corrected, but let me address your main question a bit more directly:

> ```
> (base) paloma@DESKTOP-ISCC0ON:~$ cd Documents
> -bash: cd: Documents: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> Can somebody tell me why is this happening and what can I do, please?

You appear to be wondering why this isn't taking you to the `Documents` folder in your *Windows* home directory.

It's important to understand that the home directory in Ubuntu/WSL is *not* the same as your Windows home directory, nor should it be.  Your Ubuntu home directory is in a virtual SSD provided by WSL.  This virtual SSD provides the *Linux* compatible filesystem that Ubuntu needs, whereas your Windows drive is formatted as NTFS and won't have 100% compatibility.

WSL *does* provide a way to get to the Windows files (including your home directory), as mentioned by @Tooster.

From inside Ubuntu:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/<your_Windows_username>
ls
```

That should show you all the files and directories in your Windows profile (a.k.a. home) folder.

Also perhaps reading as additional background -- My answer to [Where is WSL located on my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1380253/1165986).

Answer (score 2):

First of all try to format code and output from terminals using the [fenced code block format](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks).

And now to the meritum.

- current working directory is the directory you are in. Your home directory  (often denoted with `~`) is usually located in the `/home/<username>/`
- `ls` - command listing files **in the current directory**
- `ls [arguments...]` - this command lists the files **inside directories provided as arguments**
- `cd [argument]` - change directory command. using it without argument takes you to **your home directory**
- `/` is root directory in linux and an absolute paths start with it
- `.` is a current directory and if path starts with `./something` or without it `something`, then current directory is assumed (path is relative to current location)
- `..` is parent directory.

Based on the `(base)` in thee prompt and on the names of the files above, I'm gonna say that you are using [conda](https://conda.io/) environment on your WSL (Windows subsystem for linux). Why are you using it is not my business, but you seem to have skipped a few steps when learning linux and WSL first. Try starting with https://linuxjourney.com/ (especially command line section and filesystem section). Then learn about differences in linux and windows structure.

---

**@EDIT** because I only noticed you are using Linux **on Windows**

Because linux' and windows' filesystems are a bit different, when you start linux on windows a virtual filesystem is created for you. To access your windows files from linux you would have to access `/mnt/<drive>/<...windows files>` (note the `/` at the beginning - that's an absolute path)

Linux is structured as a single tree rooted at `/` and external filesystems are usually mounted at `/mnt` (read [hier(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) for more info). Windows' filesystem is composed of "drives" - single trees rooted at `C:/`, `D:/` etc., so it's only natural for both of those systems to have different mechanism for accessing each other's files.

Read more at https://ling123labs.com/posts/WSL-files-in-Windows-and-vice-versa/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily access your Windows "Documents" folder from WSL, you can create a symbolic link from your home directory:

```
ln -s '/mnt/c/Users/YourUserNameHere/Documents' ./WinDocuments
```

You can do that for Documents or you could just link your Windows home directory.