# Can't access Desktop via Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I am brand new to using the command line so bare with me.  I am not able to access my Desktop from my root directory. The furthest I can get is /home/sam and then there isn't anything from here. I have tried /home/SAM/Desktop and starting from /. The only way I can access folders is using /mnt/c/Users/Sam/Documents/ - however I believe this is storing items in a mounted drive, which is causing my endless problems when trying to run repositories via VS Code. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You might be able to give help if you provide some info on how your ubuntu runs. Is it ubuntu inside a VM or some kind? Or via the Ubuntu app on Windows?

Comment: Apologies - via the app on windows

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the /home/SAM folder doesn't correspond to your windows desktop folder if you're using the WSL (windows subsystem for Linux; I'm guessing that's what you're using), as the WSL is virtual machine you have just installed and doesn't contain anything (still has no data). The easiest to find your stuff in the WSL's ubuntu would be to create symbolic links to wherever you want to find the rest of your data, but the WSL won't "transcribe" your data into the linux virtual machine "out of the box"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-an) describes a lot about how the 2 filesystems overlap with each other. A trick I tried was setting your $HOME variable to /mnt/c/Users/Sam/Documents/ or creating a symlink in /home/sam that points to that `C` share:

```
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/Sam/Documents/project.git /home/sam/project.git
```

That saves you some typing.